My first drone broke 2 esp32
i'm trying to build my first drone. i have already built some drones using flight control, pixhawk and other stuffs. But i really enjoyed the idea to build a lighter, cheaper and smaller one, all from scratch, that's why i 'm saying my "first" drone . about the Power and Motors, i'm using a 11.1volt 60c battery lipo connected to a pdb matek xt60. i have 4 esc 30A too with incorporated bec, and 4 a2212/6t 2200kv (connected to the pdb)
(i've bought this kit for esc and motors: amazon product)
about the control, i tried to use an esp32, with an mpu6050, and a 3.3v magnetometer, i've tried to add an nrf24l radio, but i thought that using a websocket was a better idea. by the way ...
testing the microcontroller and the sensors with the websocket control worked fine, but i started having problem trying to connect the escs with the microcontroller for controlling them properly, i've tried to connect all the grounds of the 4 escs to the esp32, and the control pin too, but after that my pc wasn't able to recognize the esp32 anymore, i've connected the 5v too to the esp32 (dumb idea) and obviously broked another esp32, i've tried with an arduino, and even thought weird things were happening like the fact that he wasn't switching off, they worked fine there. but i'm not fine using arduino, and i know even thought they worked they are still not working too, and i 'm really trying to use esp32. what i have to do? do i have to build/buy an external board for esp32, change microcontroller or buy another flight control (i'm trying to avoid the flight control idea) or maybe i have to study more before having this dumb ideas?

I came across your post and realized I'm working on the exact same project—building a drone from scratch using the ESP32-WROVER for control. I'm also exploring the use of ESCs, motors, and sensors like the MPU6050. What amazed me is that I’m using the exact same components as the ones linked in your post! If possible, could you please share your GitHub link? I would greatly appreciate your help. By the way, I also found this new repository that might be of interest:
https://github.com/okalachev/flix Please be in touch with me!
